# Looping with promises in node returns same response

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

When using q I get the same response the amount of times it loops:

```
function start() {
    var the_promises = [];
    var api_info = config.AFV
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var extPath = '/search/'
    var callType = 'GET'
    var mymd = buildmd5(api_info, extPath, callType);

    for(var page=1;page<4;page++) {

        console.log('getting page:'+page)
        new Client().get(url'+page, function(data, response){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        the_promises.push(deferred.promise);
    }  
    return Q.all(the_promises);
}

start().then(function (clips) {
    inspect(clips)
});
```

Output: 
    resultPageNumber: [ '1' ],
    resultPageNumber: [ '1' ],
    resultPageNumber: [ '1' ],
    resultPageNumber: [ '1' ],

I feel like I might have the var deferred = Q.defer(); in the wrong place and it snot saving to different promises. I know this version of the code isnt functional but I'm only concerned about the promises. Thank you!

Comment: Move `var deferred = Q.defer();` inside your loop.

Comment: If you have multiple `promises`, you need multiple `defer` objects. You are reusing the same `defer` for all promises which is most likely the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new deferred for every new Client. And toss that loop body in a immediately invoked function to properly scope the var.

```
function start() {
    var the_promises = [];
    var api_info = config.AFV;
    var extPath = '/search/';
    var callType = 'GET';
    var mymd = buildmd5(api_info, extPath, callType);

    for(var page=1;page<4;page++) {
        (function() {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            console.log('getting page:'+page);
            new Client().get('url'+page, function(data, response){
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
           the_promises.push(deferred.promise);
        }());
    }  
    return Q.all(the_promises);
}

start().then(function (clips) {
    inspect(clips);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the existing solution, it's risky. What happens if one promise errors? What happens if you have another issue in your code?

It is my advice to **always promisify the lowest primitive possible**.

In our case. I would promisify the `Client`s `.get` method.

```
Client.prototype.getAsync = function(url){
   var d = Q.defer(); // or better, using Q.Promise(
   // please also consider adding a d.reject on the error case.
   this.get(url, function(data){ d.resolve(data); }); 
   return d.promise;
}
```

This new api would let you do:

```
var promises = [1,2,3,4].map(function(page){
    return new Client().getAsync("url"+page);
});
return Q.all(promises);
```

And then get a similar API to what Dan's answer has. This is a lot nicer in my opinion, and a lot less error prone.